# Whitespace delimiter not working - StringTokenizer

Tags: whitespace, token, delimiter, stringtokenizer

I have to use a whitespace to tokenize a string, with this constructor:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, " ");
```

which I think it's the same of

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
```

The problem is, when I try to use a whitespace as a delimiter, it takes only the first token so the output is like this:

```
3 5 + //this is the string which has to be tokenized
3 | //these are the tokens it actually takes
```

If I do the same thing with a comma (or any other delimiter except the whitespace), so:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(stringa, ",");
```

it works right and it takes all the tokens I need:

```
3,5,+ //this is the string which has to be tokenized
3 | 5 | //these are the tokens it actually takes
8 | //this is the result of the sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, hope this will help someone. I was using Scanner class for the string to be tokenized but in the wrong way, I had to use sc.nextLine() instead of sc.next()

Comment: Remember that you can [accept your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), to signal other users with a similar question that there is an answer that solves that issue.